# How to write the select statement in this condition?

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

I have a query which i am using to filter the grid

```
     SELECT * FROM Resources
              WHERE ResourceName  ='" + ResourceName + "' 
              AND  Status = '" + status + "' "
```

and  my grid looks like this

```
  ResourceID|ResourceName|Status
```

I had added the  ResorceName and Status in a dropdown for filtering the grid now my problem is that in this select statement if any of the paramaters is null the data is not Binded to the grid but if I pass both the parameters it filters the grid and gives the required row or filtered row from the grid... Can anyone tell me how do I write select statement if any of the parameter is null.

Comment: what if both are null? well you can write if/when condition in sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look it the below post on catch all queries

[Catch All Examples](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)

Answer (score 1):

In terms of fixing your problem quickly, something like this would work...

```
Select * From Resources Where (ResourceName = '"+ ResourceName + "' OR ResourceName IS NULL) AND (Status = '" + Status +"' OR Status IS NULL)
```

That however is NOT an acceptable piece of code, as it is vulnerable to SQL injection. In essence, suppose the ResourceName that is passed in is

```
'; Drop Table Resources; --
```

You probably don't need me to tell you what that does.

My advice is to ALWAYS make use of SQLCommand objects in .Net - also known as "Prepared Statements" in other languages. It prevents these kind of tricks...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Resources
WHERE (ResourceName  = CASE WHEN '" + ResourceName + "' IS NULL THEN ResourceName  ELSE '" + ResourceName + "' END) //do same for other parameter
```

Comment: I tried this but again the same problem there are no rows affected i have a null in any of the parameters